# How to get proper outerHTML from jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good evening everybody

I am using jquery-plugin has next lines of code:

```
return '<td>' + field.setValue(field.html, content)[0].outerHTML + '</td>';
```

The `setValue` in my code

```
    field_templates: {
        'number': {
            html: '<input type="number" name="monday-start">',
            getValue: function (input) {
                return $(input).val();
            },
            setValue: function (input, value) {
                if (value) {
                    return $(input).val('66').addClass('setValue').data('dtv-val', 555);
                }
                return $(input).val('');
            }
        }
    },
```

The result of the code is next:

```
<input type="number" name="monday-start" class="setValue">
```

but, I want to get the follow

```
<input type="number" name="monday-start" value="66" class="setValue" data-dtv-val="555">
```

Please, explain me where I wrong? What I not understood? How can I get the `input` has required me attributes? I not enough to know JavaScript, because I will happy to get a link to JS documentation where described theory of my question

Comment: What is the value of `content`?  Where is it set?

Comment: @jmargolisvt, the `content` does not matter in my case. it's 2nd argument of the method. I not used it now.

Comment: There is a difference between setting *value attribute* and *value property*. The attribute is not usually important after element has rendered unless you need to reset a form. When a user inputs something...it is only available in the *value property* and the attribute doesn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/):**
`.val('66')` val 66 in it, like if you've typed something, not the attribute `value` itself;

---

**[.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/):**

`.addClass('setValue')` will add a class called 'setValue', it's ok; and

---

**[.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/):**
`.data('dtv-val', 555)` it won't change anything in that way, read API for more info.

---

**[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is what you're searching for:**

```js
$('#ipt').attr('value','66').attr('class','setValue').attr('data-dtv-val', '555');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="ipt">
```

(you can change `.attr('class', 'setValue')` to `.addClass('setValue')` if you want)

Comment: It was my idea to use .attr() ??

Comment: `attr('class')` and `addClass()` do different things. Latter preserves existing classes. `attr('class'..` Will wipe out any existing classes

Comment: @YouneL this idea is helped me. No matter whose it was. Thanks

Comment: That difference in time is because I was trying to improve my answer with the links and explaining what&#39;s happening. I&#39;m sorry. :(

Answer (score 1):

Using `.data()` method will store key-value pairs to the matched element without affecting its html part, you have to use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

this line:

```
 return $(input).val('66').addClass('setValue').data('dtv-val', 555);
```

change it to:

```
 return $(input).val('66').addClass('setValue').attr('dtv-val', 555);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are getting what you want, it just doesn't look how you expect.

With jQuery, it won't put the data element into the HTML. It'll just store it in a kind of hidden way.

However, if you were to get the element again and to check it's data, you'll see that it is actually there.

```
console.log($('[name="monday-start"]').data('dtv-val'))
```